# How does the energy of the system in state $\psi(x,0)$ relates with parity-even and parity-odd $E_n^+$, $E_l^-$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

#### Context

Let's say we have an infinite potential well of width $L$
\begin{equation*}
  V(x) = \begin{cases}
    0, \quad x \in [-L/2, L/2] \\
    +\infty, \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

The energy eigenstates of a particle trapped in this potential form two distinct sets of even $\phi_n^+$ and odd $\phi_l^-$ wave functions with respectives eigenvalues $E_n^+$ and $E_l^-$ given by

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rl}
    \phi_n^+ = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \cos(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{L}) \quad ;& E_n^+ = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}{L^2}
  \end{array} \\
  \begin{array}{rl}
    \phi_l^- = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin(\frac{2l\pi x}{L}) \quad ;& E_l^- = \frac{2\hbar^2}{m} \frac{l^2 \pi^2}{L^2}
  \end{array} \\
\end{align*}

with $n = 0, 1, 2,\dots$ and $l = 1, 2,\dots$

#### Facts

=> At $t = 0$, the system is described by a wave function $\psi(x, 0)$ and
$\psi(x,0)$ is a superposition of the ground state and one excited state.

=> The 2 possible results of the measurement of the system energy are equally probable.

=> $\langle H \rangle = \frac{5\hbar^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}$

#### Question

I have some trouble to determine the 2 possible values which can be obtained when measuring the energy of the system in the state $\psi(x, 0)$.

#### My reasoning

Because $\psi(x,0)$ is a superposition of the ground state and one excited state, we have:

\begin{equation*}
  \psi(x,0) = c_0 \psi_0(x,0) + c_N \psi_N(x,0), \quad N \in \mathbb{N}_{\ast} 
\end{equation*}

Computing the expectation value of $\hat{H}$:
\begin{align*}
  \langle H \rangle 
    &= \langle \psi|H|\psi \rangle \\
    &= \langle c_0 \psi_0(x,0) + c_N \psi_N(x,0)|E|c_0 \psi_0(x,0) + c_N \psi_N(x,0) \rangle \\
    &= |c_0|^2 E_0 \langle \psi_0|\psi_0 \rangle + |c_N|^2 E_N \langle \psi_N|\psi_N \rangle + c_0^*c_N E_N \langle \psi_0|\psi_N \rangle + c_N^*c_0 E_0 \langle \psi_N|\psi_0 \rangle \\
    &= |c_0|^2 E_0 + |c_N|^2 E_N \\
    &= \frac{5\hbar^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}
\end{align*}

Because the 2 possible results of the measurement of the system energy are equally probable, $|c_0|^2 = \frac{1}{2} = |c_N|^2$:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{5\hbar^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}
    &= \frac{1}{2} (E_0 + E_N) \\
  \frac{5\hbar^2\pi^2}{mL^2}
    &= E_0 + E_N
\end{align*}

We know that,
\begin{equation*}
  E_0 = E_0^+ = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\pi^2}{L^2}
\end{equation*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
  E_N 
    &= \frac{5\hbar^2\pi^2}{mL^2} - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\pi^2}{L^2} \\
    &= \frac{9\hbar^2\pi^2}{mL^2}
\end{align*}

So, does $E_n = E_1^+$ ? I don't understand how the energy measured of the system in the state $\psi(x,0)$ relates with $E_n^+$ and $E_l^-$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. How are the $\psi$s and the $\phi$s related?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post so it's clearer

Comment: There’s quite a bit of confusion here because you do not use $E_n^\pm$ in the second part of your post.

Comment: Computing $\langle \hat{H} \rangle$ and knowing that $\psi(x,0)$ is a superposition of the ground state and one excited state, I get that the two possible energy value are $E_0^+$ and $E_1^+$ and so we take the even solution ($\cos$).
Eventually we have, $\psi(x,0) = c_0 \phi_0^+ + c_1\phi_1^+$.

Am I right ?